# turn array columns into rows ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, transform

I have an array of arrays called puzzle and I'm trying to return a new array with the first array consisting of

```
["a", "s", "i", "o", "s", "u", "z"]
```

Then the next array consisting of the array"s second index

```
["k", "o", "t", "t", "e", "r", "s"]
```

etc etc.  What are some good ways to do this.  I was thinking of using map and two counters but could not get them to operate or or increase at different times properly. Any help would be awesome.  Thanks!

I want to return a new array from this `puzzle`:

```
puzzle = [
  ["a", "k", "f", "o", "x", "e", "s"],
  ["s", "o", "a", "w", "a", "h", "p"],
  ["i", "t", "c", "k", "e", "t", "n"],
  ["o", "t", "s", "d", "h", "o", "h"],
  ["s", "e", "x", "g", "s", "t", "a"],
  ["u", "r", "p", "i", "w", "e", "u"],
  ["z", "s", "b", "n", "u", "i", "r"]
]
```

Comment: I noticed you never accept the answers given to your questions. Make sure to go over your questions some time and accept the best answers given they solve your question. This way you let the community know, that the problem is solved and at the same time you reward the effort of the one, who has provided the solution

Comment: Since `puzzle` is an instance of the class [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html), you should first look through that class' instance methods (see link). If you don't find something there that works (but you should), look through the the module [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html). `Array` `include`s that module, so all of the instance methods in `Enumerable` are available for use by instances of `Array`, just as though they had been created as an `Array` instance method.

Comment: Downvoted due to: 1) no effort shown at all; 2) correct answer is not accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Array#`transpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) is there for you:

```
puzzle = [
  ["a", "k", "f", "o", "x", "e", "s"],
  ["s", "o", "a", "w", "a", "h", "p"],
  ["i", "t", "c", "k", "e", "t", "n"],
  ["o", "t", "s", "d", "h", "o", "h"],
  ["s", "e", "x", "g", "s", "t", "a"],
  ["u", "r", "p", "i", "w", "e", "u"],
  ["z", "s", "b", "n", "u", "i", "r"]
]
puzzle.transpose
# => [["a", "s", "i", "o", "s", "u", "z"],
#  ["k", "o", "t", "t", "e", "r", "s"],
#  ["f", "a", "c", "s", "x", "p", "b"],
#  ["o", "w", "k", "d", "g", "i", "n"],
#  ["x", "a", "e", "h", "s", "w", "u"],
#  ["e", "h", "t", "o", "t", "e", "i"],
#  ["s", "p", "n", "h", "a", "u", "r"]]
```

Comment: `transpose` is the way to go, but `puzzle.first.zip(*puzzle.drop(1))` also works. See [Enumerable#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) and [Enumerable#drop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop). For arrays that can be transposed, the methods `transpose` and `zip` are ying and yang.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Array
  def my_transpose!
    size.times do |i|
      0.upto(i) do |j|                                   # iterate only through lower half
        self[i][j], self[j][i] = self[j][i], self[i][j]  # swap rows and cols
      end
    end
    self                                                 # return the array itself
  end

  def my_transpose
    dup.map(&:dup).my_transpose!                         # inner arrays are dup'ed, too
  end
end
```

OR if you don't need a mutator....

`.transpose` method then pick the array you want with `[]`

```
puzzle.transpose[0]
```

The [0] says give me the first result.

```
puzzle.transpose[0]
=> ["a", "s", "i", "o", "s", "u", "z"]

puzzle.transpose[1]
=> ["k", "o", "t", "t", "e", "r", "s"]
```

Comment: you do realize, that your answer brings nothing new compared to mine and was given like 10 minutes later, right? :)